# maven installation issues under WIndows 10

Tags: java, maven, windows-10

I was installing maven 3.3.9 under windows 10.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

I added following environment variables

1. `M2= %M2_HOME%\bin`
2. `M2_HOME = C:\DEV Tools\apache-maven-3.3.9`
3. `MAVEN_OPTS= -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dmaven.artifact.threads=3`
4. And I added M2 to my Path

After that each time I run `mvn -v` to check Maven installation.

```
 Done: MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\VANN00643378A.bin
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\VANN00643378A.bin
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxxx 
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxxxxx 
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks 
     -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data
Error: Could not find or load main class Files
```

*without linebreaks*

I have tried reinstall Maven and it didnt work. 
Can anyone tell why it saying: **Error: Could not find or load main class Files** ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you just go to the M2_HOME/bin and do a mvn -v to see if that works?

Comment: Hello!  I cd into the M2_HOME/bin and tried mvn -v. The message is still same. ...

Comment: please check the answer by Jim, that should help

Answer (score 2):

maven is searching for a file named `Files` , because there is a <kbd>space</kbd> two times in Attributes `-Djaxax.net...` in `C:\Program Files (X86)\ ...` .

Look for the place where these attributes are set and wrap the expression
 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\VANN00643378A.bin` with `"  "`

In contrast to Linux or other Unix derivates, this is necessary when defining environment variables which values contain spaces.